# curl works on cli but not when put in bash script

Tags: bash, curl

I run this command from the CLI and it works fine...

```
curl -H Content-Type:text/plain -vLk https://10.42.0.197/exec/show%20ver --user chartley:<pw omitted>
```

Now when I put it into a bash script I get the following...

```
* About to connect() to 10.42.0.197 port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 10.42.0.197... connected
* Connected to 10.42.0.197 (10.42.0.197) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=ASA Temporary Self Signed Certificate
*       start date: Jul 18 20:53:46 2013 GMT
*       expire date: Jul 16 20:53:46 2023 GMT
*       common name: ASA Temporary Self Signed Certificate
*       issuer: CN=ASA Temporary Self Signed Certificate
* Server auth using Basic with user 'chartley'
> GET /exec/show%20version HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic
> User-Agent: Firefox
> Host: 10.42.0.197
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:text/plain
> < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized < Date: Tue, 04 Apr 2017 22:06:53 UTC < Connection: close < Content-Type: text/html < Expires: Thu, 16 eb
1989 00:00:00 GMT
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this. < WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Authentication" < <HEAD><TITLE>Authorization
Required</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Authorization Required</H1>Browser
not authentication-capable or authentication failed.</BODY>

* Closing connection #0
```

I had the curl command echoed out with variable expansion performed and it's character for character with the command that works on the CLI.

What am I missing?

Here is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'

echo "Gimme yo password foo!!"
read -s pass

pass=$(echo $pass | sed 's/[(\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\))&]/\\&/g')

if [[ "$2" =~ [:space:] ]];
then
        CMD=`echo $2 | sed 's/ /\%20/g'`
        #echo "space matched"
        #echo "$2"
fi

if [[ "$CMD" =~ */* ]];
then
        CMD=`echo $2 | 's/[\/]/\%2f/g'`
        #echo "Slash matched"
        #echo "$2"
fi

curl -H Content-Type:text/plain -vLk https://$1/exec/$CMD --user "$USER:$pass"
```

... and it is run as such... ASA_do 10.42.0.197 "show ver"

Here is the output having added "set -x" in the bash script...

```
[chartley@s324phx-syslog ~]$ ASA_do 10.42.0.197 "show version"
+ echo 'Gimme yo password foo!!'
Gimme yo password foo!!
+ read -s pass
++ echo '<omitted>'
++ sed 's/[(\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\))&]/\\&/g'
+ pass='<pw omitted>'
+ [[ show version =~ [:space:] ]]
++ echo 'show version'
++ sed 's/ /\%20/g'
+ CMD=show%20version
+ [[ show%20version =~ */* ]]
+ curl -H Content-Type:text/plain -vLk https://10.42.0.197/exec/show%20version --user 'chartley:<pw omitted>'
* About to connect() to 10.42.0.197 port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 10.42.0.197... connected
* Connected to 10.42.0.197 (10.42.0.197) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=ASA Temporary Self Signed Certificate
*       start date: Jul 18 20:53:46 2013 GMT
*       expire date: Jul 16 20:53:46 2023 GMT
*       common name: ASA Temporary Self Signed Certificate
*       issuer: CN=ASA Temporary Self Signed Certificate
* Server auth using Basic with user 'chartley'
> GET /exec/show%20version HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic <omitted>
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.18 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: 10.42.0.197
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:text/plain
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Thu, 06 Apr 2017 20:39:38 UTC
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html
< Expires: Thu, 16 Feb 1989 00:00:00 GMT
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Authentication"
<
<HEAD><TITLE>Authorization Required</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Authorization Required</H1>Browser not authentication-capable or authentication failed.</BODY>

* Closing connection #0
```

This is the script with it working using eval...

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
set -x
echo "Gimme yo password foo!!"
IFS=$'\n' read -r -s -p 'Password:' pass

pass=$(echo $pass | sed 's/[(\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\))&]/\\&/g' | sed "s/'//g")

if [[ "$2" =~ [:space:] ]];
then
        CMD=`echo $2 | sed 's/ /\%20/g'`
        #echo "space matched"
        #echo "$2"
fi

if [[ "$CMD" =~ */* ]];
then
        CMD=`echo $2 | 's/[\/]/\%2f/g'`
        #echo "Slash matched"
        #echo "$2"
fi

eval curl -H Content-Type:text/plain -vLk https://$1/exec/$CMD --user "$USER:$pass"
```

Comment: From the CLI please provide the output of `type curl`, and `which curl`.

Comment: Please add `set -x` command on second line of your script and show us the output.

Comment: `[chartley@s324phx-syslog ~]$ type curl
curl is /usr/bin/curl`

`[chartley@s324phx-syslog ~]$ which curl
/usr/bin/curl`

Comment: `show ver` on one side and `show version` on the other -- pertinent?

Comment: BTW, while the `set -x` logs show us it's not an immediate cause to your problem, your code runs afoul of [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo). And you want `[[ $CMD = */* ]]` or `[[ $CMD =~ / ]]`; `*/*` isn't a legal ERE expression, so it isn't valid on the right-hand side of `=~`. (And you should use lower-case names for your own variables -- see the fourth paragraph of the [relevant POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), specifying all-uppercase name as used for variables with meaning to OS or shell).

Comment: ...yes, you're modifying `IFS`, but newline literals are things that happen, and string-splitting isn't the only thing that quotes avoid -- glob expansion is a thing too.

Comment: (in particular, newline literals can happen in your `pass` variable because you haven't used the `-r` argument to `read` -- if the string entered ends with a backslash, then `read` will treat the following newline as literal data and continue to prompt. And if it contains a literal backslash somewhere else, it'll be consumed by `read` itself rather than put into the generated variable).

Comment: Anyhow. Besides the `ver`-vs-`version` difference, the other thing unaccounted for is the actual password itself -- on a 403, that **is** rather unavoidable pertinent. Does the `set -x` output show the exact same text for the argument following `--user` between the interactive and scripted cases? (You can use `set -x` at the command line to get the same logging that `bash -x` provides for your scripts).

Comment: As another aside -- if you're adding the backslashes to your passwords because you expect those backslashes to be **shell** syntax... they aren't shell syntax; they're passed directly and literally to curl.

Comment: Thank you Charles for all of your pointers. However those things are not malforming the command generated. The password's special characters are backslash escaped and the bash generated command is syntactically identical to the manual command that runs successfully at the CLI. There must be something else like an environmental difference perhaps relating to the terminal type or something outside my knowledge level.

Comment: Still looking for a solution to this. I read about the bounty thing and I would give all 8 of my reputation units but I can't as you need at least 50.

Comment: BTW, edits *just* to bump are frowned on. Try to at least make a material improvement -- for instance, *showing* (as opposed to just telling) that none of the suggestions made in comments were helpful.

Comment: As 1st step; put into the shell script **exactly** your working command, with the hardcoded `username:password` and nothing more. You will see, the command will work as in plain command-line.

Comment: As step2. - if the above is confirmed, thats mean that all speculations about environment and such are wrong, and you must search the error source in the password-mungling part of your script... :)

Comment: `bash -x` is your friend. Just do things step-by-step - (small steps) - and try how it works. When stops work, you will know the last (wrong) step... That's all about the debugging-mystery :)

Comment: @jm666 That should have been obvious but I didn't even think of that, thank you. It executed just fine so I now know that although the command is echoed identically something isn't the same when passed to curl.

Comment: Right. What `set -x` emits is syntactically identical to what you pass on the command line. What `echo` emits is not. (Basically, `echo` emits only **literal** contents from its arguments -- if your quotes, escapes, etc. are literal instead of syntactic, then you have a big problem, for reasons given in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)).

Comment: Anyhow, that's why I wanted you to compare `set -x` logs from the two approaches -- if you'd done so, we would have found this problem much, much earlier.

Comment: For whatever reason adding "eval" before the curl command made it work. Still not sure what was failing with variable expansion but eval took care of it. Thank you @jm666

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to add "eval" to the curl command.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
set -x
echo "Gimme yo password foo!!"
IFS=$'\n' read -r -s -p 'Password:' pass

pass=$(echo $pass | sed 's/[(\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\))&]/\\&/g' | sed "s/'//g")

if [[ "$2" =~ [:space:] ]];
then
        CMD=`echo $2 | sed 's/ /\%20/g'`
        #echo "space matched"
        #echo "$2"
fi

if [[ "$CMD" =~ */* ]];
then
        CMD=`echo $2 | 's/[\/]/\%2f/g'`
        #echo "Slash matched"
        #echo "$2"
fi

eval curl -H Content-Type:text/plain -vLk https://$1/exec/$CMD --user "$USER:$pass"
```

Comment: If it is the last command in your script, `exec` is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use:

```
read -r -s -p 'Password:' pass
curl ..... needed args  .... --user "$USER:$pass"
```

without any password mungling and like. (probably don't want change the `IFS` too (yes, the `IFS=$'\n'` helps when the password contains trailing space... but first try without any IFS change...) and after `IFS=$'\n' read -r -s -p 'Password:' pass`

Comment: I did remove the IFS, set -r and -p on the pass read statement to no avail, but you led me to the answer with your suggestion. I don't think eval is the best solution but it makes it work so I'm happy. Thank you @jm666

Comment: @CodyHartley Don't understand why you need some eval. The eval is (usually) dangerous. But you know what do you need. :) happy programming.